# Connect Visual Basic's ComboBox with Access's tables

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, combobox

I'm working on Visual Basic express 2010 and Microsoft Access. I made the database and relationships with Access, connected them to VB just fine.
My problem is, I have a table called Address_Table, it contains only one field called Address_Name. The table Address_Table is connected to The_Student table to a field called Student_Address with "Enforce referential integrity".

I can't upload images I'm really sorry, I really tried.

Problem #1 is:
In visual basic, I want to make a combobox where the user choose from choices imported from the Address_Name and then after he clicks on the add button, the choice will be added to the database to the Student_Address field.
I mean, Address_Name will contains values like A, B, C. I want these values to appear in the combobox and after he chooses one of them, he click add and the choice will be inserted in the database.

Problem #2 is:
Ah sorry it's also about combobox. it's about two comboboxes where when you choose from the first one like from table country, you choose America, then in the other combobox only America's states will appear. Or when you choose England, only England's cities will appear and so on.

*Table Country have one field named: Country_Name.
*Table Scholarship contains field: Scholarship_To, Country_Name, City_Name
*Table City have the fileds: City_Name, Country

*Table Scholarship and Country both connected to a table named Student_Info, Country connected to ABC field and Scholarship to New field.
*Table Country connected to Scholarship and City tables to the following fields: Country_Name in Scholarship and Country in City table.
*Scholarship table is connected to City table: City_Name with Country fields.
All which have "Enforce referential integrity".

Oh God I hope someone understands me, I tried to provide everything, please help me.

```
Public Class frmStudent
Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
 Private Sub RefreshData()
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Student_ID as [ID], " & _
                                         "Student_Name as [Name], Student_Gender, Student_Phone, Student_Address " & _
                                         " FROM The_Student ORDER BY Student_ID", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'fill data to datatable
    da.Fill(dt)

    'offer data in data table into datagridview
    Me.dgvData.DataSource = dt

    'close connection
    cnn.Close()
End Sub

 Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection if it is not yet open
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    cmd.Connection = cnn
    'check whether add new or update
    If Me.txtstdID.Tag & "" = "" Then
        'add new 
        'add data to table
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO The_Student(Student_ID, Student_Name, Student_Gender, Student_Phone)" & _
                        " VALUES(" & Me.txtstdID.Text & ",'" & Me.txtStdName.Text & "','" & _
                        Me.cboGender.Text & "','" & Me.txtPhone.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else
        'update data in table
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE The_Student " & _
                    " SET Student_ID=" & Me.txtstdID.Text & _
                    ", Student_Name='" & Me.txtStdName.Text & "'" & _
                    ", Student_Gender='" & Me.cboGender.Text & "'" & _
                    ", Student_Phone='" & Me.txtPhone.Text & "'" & _
                    ", Student_Address='" & Me.txtAddress.Text & "'" & _
                    " WHERE Student_ID=" & Me.txtstdID.Tag
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End If
    'refresh data in list
    RefreshData()
    'clear form
    Me.btnClear.PerformClick()

    'close connection
    cnn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub frmStudent_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\data.mdb"
    '
    'get data into list
    Me.RefreshData()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This has exactly what you are looking for. These are generally referred to as look-up lists. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb466226.aspx#formsoverdata

So, in particular, video #5 should be the one that you are looking for. Since you are using VB + Access, I would recommend that you abandon OleDb commands and use the strongly typed Datasets and Adapters, etc, unless you have a compelling reason not to. Even if you do, building the lookups out the way she does in these videos will generate the Insert/Update/Delete statements for you to satisfy the constraints (They are properties of the adapters).

Comment: Thank you so much for the link, It was very helpful but I still couldn't find a direct answer for what I'm looking for. The code above with OleDb commands and such is from a tutorial. I'm still very early on visual basic so it's hard for me to completely understand your comment on what I should choose or what I should change. Can you guide me? Thank you

Comment: Well, the OleDb namespace has a collection of generic data access components. That approach uses commands and data adapters to perform data operations. Conversely, you can initiate strongly typed ADO objects by adding a dataset to your project (just like you would add a form). Once you configure that dataset with the wizard, you can use its autogenerated table adapters and binding sources to wire up your UI.

Comment: That forms over data video series has numerous examples of how this works, too. It's worth learning both approaches, but your case sounds like a really good use case for those typed datasets, since you need advanced binding and lookups and you dont have a lot of experience yet.